# How can I search in Vim, using regular expressions for letters (both ascii and non ascii)?

Tags: regex, vim, unicode

In .NET, `\p{L}` matches any ascii or non-ascii letter (so it will match both `a` and `ü`).

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop

Is there a Vim equivalent for this?

In Vim `\a` or `\w` will only match characters in range `[a-z]` (or `[0-9A-Za-z_]`).

Comment: For reference: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html ; it looks like you may be able to play around with e.g. `\P`, i.e. printable characters (allowing multi-byte) excluding digits. You may have to override the value for the `isprint` option.

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitly tell vim which ranges of hex values to match. This is kind of a shotgun approach, but if you know what the possible ranges (like UTF-8 for example) this would work:

```
/[\x7f-\xffa-zA-Z]
```

You can also search for explicit unicode values by entering in the unicode character directly or it's code in the following format:

```
/\%u0300
```

Comment: There is a limit to how many chars are allowed in a character class (255, IIRC).