# search vim using utf-8 code

Tags: vim

I am facing a problem with a file with lots of dead characters ( maybe because of porting from multiple file systems and code pages ). Hence, I just want to find all the characters that are beyond 127 and delete them by using the search and replace method.

This did not help

[How can I search in Vim, using regular expressions for letters (both ascii and non ascii)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540923/how-can-i-search-in-vim-using-regular-expressions-for-letters-both-ascii-and-n)

There are many characters whose

```
ga
```

returns me for example 65533.

Or in other words, is there any way to search all 65533's and replace them with nothing in VIM?

Comment: Does `:%s/[^\x00-\x7f]//g` work?

Comment: Bingo. Will accept as an answer. Whats the \x for? Hexadecimal? Is it possible to look for decimal or octal values too?

Comment: See `:help \%x`.

Comment: Sure: `\d32`, `\o40`, `\x20`, `\u20`, `\U20` are all space (see somewhere under `:help /\]`).